# C# System.Timers on server with countdown

Tags: c#, xaml, timer, visual-studio-2013

I hope you can help me out a bit.

So the main problem is: how can i create a server-side timer, which has a 60-second countdown with an interval of 1 sec, and if the time hits zero, it should do an action? f.e. skip turn of a player.

It is based on a cardgame with multiclients and one server. On the client, I do have a timer, but I guess it won't make any sense, since the only one, who can actually see the timer is the player himself, so i do need the logic on the server to display the time to all the other clients.

Here is my code so far. But no actions so far.

```
...
using System.Timers;

namespace CardGameServer{

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
public sealed class Player : IPlayer
{
    public Timer timer;
    int remainingtime = 60;

 public void timerAnzeigen()
    {
        timer = new Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimeEvent);
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void OnTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        remainingtime--;
        if (remainingtime == 0)
        {
            drawCard();
            nextPlayer();
            remainingtime = 60;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not simply send the remaining time integer to the server, with a flag indicating what it is, then have the server simply forward it to all clients?

Comment: I agree with @StevenMills another option would be if it is a turn based game have them start timers at the same relative time and then have a holding screen once the client whose turn it is timer fires it's event tell all the other clients that the event has occurred. Once all client return they receive the event start the next turn.

Comment: i can see your point, didnt come up with that though, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed Visual Studio 2013 in your tag, so I assume you are using C# 4.5. In that case I would recommend *against* the `Timer` class and instead to use `Task` with `async/await`.

For example:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public sealed class TaskTimer
{
    Action onTick;
    CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }

    public TaskTimer(TimeSpan interval, Action onTick)
    {
        this.Interval = interval;
        this.onTick = onTick;
    }

    public async void Start()
    {
        Stop();

        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        this.IsRunning = true;

        while (this.IsRunning)
        {
            await Task.Delay(this.Interval, cts.Token);

            if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                this.IsRunning = false;
                break;
            }

            if (onTick != null)
                onTick();
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (cts != null)
            cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Then in your `Player` class:

```
sealed class Player : IPlayer
{
    static readonly TimeSpan OneSecondDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    static readonly int InitialSeconds = 60;

    TaskTimer timer;
    long remainingSeconds;

    public int RemainingSeconds
    {
        get { return (int)Interlocked.Read(ref remainingSeconds); }
    }

    public Player()
    {
        ResetTimer(InitialSeconds);

        timer = new TaskTimer(OneSecondDelay, TimerTick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    void ResetTimer(int seconds)
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref remainingSeconds, seconds);
    }

    void TimerTick()
    {
        var newValue = Interlocked.Decrement(ref remainingSeconds);

        if (newValue <= 0)
        {
            // Timer has expired!
            ResetTimer(InitialSeconds);
        }
    }
}
```